# Using instanceof to change color of JLabels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am looking for away to change the text color of all my `JLabel`s with a function so I don´t have to use the `setForegroundColor` for each and every one of them.

I currently have a bunch of `JLabel`s in a panel called `Main`. I did a bit of research and came across the `instanceof` and `getComponents` method. So I've come this far:

```
main = new JPanel();
    main.setBackground(Color.red);
    tf_search = createTF();
    l_name1 = new JLabel("Name: "+ DB.findUser(1001).returnName());
    l_nick = new JLabel("Nick: " + DB.findUser(1001).returnNick());
    l_style = new JLabel("Style: ");
    l_styleshow = new JLabel(DB.findUser(1001).returnStyle());
    l_music = new JLabel("Favourite songs: ");
    l_musicshow1 = new JLabel(DB.findUser(1001).returnMusic1());
    l_musicshow2 = new JLabel(DB.findUser(1001).returnMusic2());
    l_musicshow3 = new JLabel(DB.findUser(1001).returnMusic3());
    l_blank = new JLabel("");
    l_blank2 = new JLabel("");
    l_inst = new JLabel("Instrument: ");
    l_instshow = new JLabel(DB.findUser(1001).returnInst());
    l_band = new JLabel("Band: ");
    l_bandshow = new JLabel(DB.findUser(1001).returnBand());
    b_search  = new JButton("Sök");
    b_musicchn = new JButton("Edit Profile");
    b_return = new JButton("Return to profile");


    main.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,2));
    main.add(l_name1);
    main.add(l_nick);
    main.add(l_style);
    main.add(l_styleshow);
    main.add(l_music);
    main.add(l_musicshow1);
    main.add(l_blank);
    main.add(l_musicshow2);
    main.add(l_blank2);
    main.add(l_musicshow3);
    main.add(l_band);
    main.add(l_bandshow);
    main.add(l_inst);
    main.add(l_instshow);
    main.add(b_search);
    b_search.addActionListener(new searchHandler());
    main.add(b_musicchn);
    b_musicchn.addActionListener(new editHandler());
    main.add(tf_search);
    main.add(b_return);
    b_return.addActionListener(new returnHandler());
```

And all the Panels and stuff are declared, or what to call it. ex "private JLabel l_nick, etc"

So I thought this might select all `JLabels` and turn the text to white, but my code doesn't work hehe. Is this a legit way of doing things and can you correct it, or does someone know another way. Thanks in advance!

Note: I am a student and this is for my final project in my first programming year, so I just want the code variety. If it is not possible with a massive, advanced block of code don't bother typing it out, even though your help is appreciated!

Comment: As an aside: `private JPanel  = main;` this is not valid syntax. Remove the equals.

Comment: @Michael I just wrote it of my head. I have the right syntax in my actual code. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may retrieve all child components, check if they are `JLabel`, and set the color accordingly .

```
    for (Component component : panel.getComponents()) {

        if (component instanceof JLabel) {

            component.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I did a straight copy of your code and it didn´t work(replaced "panel" with my panel). Is there something I am missing. I´m not very good with Java hehe

Comment: @Noxcore Are the labels `l_label` etc. actually components of the panel?

Comment: @Berger I will now update the question with a whole of my code and the panel in question! And the error was that it straight up didn´t do anything :S

Comment: @Noxcore : It seems to work, look at this quick test : https://pastebin.com/nqUmA142 . Maybe you meant background instead of foreground ?

Comment: @Berger I am stupid, it was my bad. I had it in a method and didn´t start it. MY BAD. Thanks for the help though, much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

don't do this:

```
main.getComponents(l_label instanceof JLabel).setForegroundColor(Color.White);
```

instead define a `List<JLabel> mylabels = ...`
populate the list:

```
myLabels.add(l_label);
myLabels.add(l_label2);
myLabels.add(l_label3);
```

and do a for enhanced

```
for(JLabel x:myLabels){

    x.setForegroundColor(Color.White);

}
```

Comment: hi @Michael, thanks, I did follow the idea, and skipped my eye compiler :)

Comment: It says "Type list doesn´t take modifiers", using Netbeans. Can´t add labels either without the modifier.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a method `getComponents` that takes a filter argument. But you could use streams to filter. Something like this:

```
Stream.of(main.getComponents()).filter(component -> component instanceOf JLabel).forEach(label -> ((JLabel)label).setForegroundColor(Color.White));
```

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with Stream, and I have no Idea what it does and what packages I need. I copied into my code and it didn´t work so idk :S Still thx tho

Comment: Downvoted because he specifically said "if it is not possible with a massive, advanced block of code don't bother typing it out". I would consider streams fairly advanced.

Comment: But it's not massive. That sentence is a logical and not a logical or ;)

Comment: @Noxcore Sry that it doesn't work directly. I assume the same problem as in Berger's answer since his and my answer are effectively the same.